# Aggregate of two or more arrays of numbers in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, aggregate

I'd like to aggregate two or more number values from several arrays in Typescript.
I have a data model as follows:

```
export class DataModel {

    date : string;
    number : any;

}
```

The main class has an array of DataModels itself:

```
export class CountryData {

    country: string;
    province: string;
    Long: any;
    Lat: any;
    dataset: DataModel[] = [];

}
```

Finally, I have an array of CountryData.

Exemple of two CountryData arrays with three DataModel values each one:

```
    let data: CountryData[];
    let country1: new CountryData();
    let country2: new CountryData();
    let countrySum: new CountryData();

    country1.dataset = [{'01/02/20',5}, {'01/03/20',10}, {'01/04/20',15}];
    country2.dataset = [{'01/02/20',5}, {'01/03/20',10}, {'01/04/20',15}];

    data.push(country1);
    data.push(country2);
```

I'd like to iterate the data variable and obtain a result like this into the countrySum.dataset:

```
[{'01/02/20',10}, {'01/03/20',20}, {'01/04/20',30}];
```

And this, will apply to n arrays in data. Anyone knows how to do this with functions like map, reduce or any other?

Thansk!

Comment: Note that the way you'd do this in TypeScript is pretty much identical to the way you'd do this in JavaScript. By limiting yourself to TypeScript, you're reducing your answer base by a considerable amount...

Comment: The code above is not valid JavaScript or TypeScript; `[{'01/02/20',5}, {'01/03/20',10}, {'01/04/20',15}]` results in a syntax error.  Please edit the question code to form a [mcve] where the only issue present is the one you're trying to solve.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks by the way... I've donne by the old school method: for ... for ....